# Limit of $x^2\sin\left(\ln\sqrt{\cos\frac{\pi}{x}}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Find $$\lim_{x\to\infty}x^2\sin\left(\ln\sqrt{\cos\frac{\pi}{x}}\right).$$

I tried substituting $x=1/t$ with $t$ approaching $0$ but the term inside the bracket is not giving me ideas on how to compute the limit.

Comment: What low quality? If I am unable to sole a question, have given it quite a time, I will ask it. What has reputation got to do with it? I earned reputation for some good questions I have asked and some good answers I have given. It has nothing to do with my intellect level. And yes, thanks for the downvote.

Comment: I removed my downvote. The question looks better. Still needs some work, like, for example, the logarithm function is better written as `$\ln$` (producing $\ln$), not `ln` (producing $ln$). Writing square roots, it is also better to use brackets like so: `$\sqrt{a}$` (producing $\sqrt{a}$) instead of `$\surd a$` producing $\surd a$

Comment: @5xum Don't forget to edit the title ;)

Comment: As said in answers and comments, Taylor series are probably the most powerful tools for limits. But, they also tell how the limit is approached. For example, in the case of the post, we can get (just using a few extra terms), $$x^2\sin\left(\ln\sqrt{\cos\frac{\pi}{x}}\right)=-\frac{\pi ^2}{4}-\frac{\pi ^4}{24 x^2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^4\right)$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do the substitution $t=1/x$, so the limit is easier:
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\sin\ln\sqrt{\cos(\pi t)}}{t^2}
$$
Now observe that, since $\ln\sqrt{\cos\pi t}$ is monotonic in a right neighborhood of $0$, you can say that
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\sin\ln\sqrt{\cos(\pi t)}}{\ln\sqrt{\cos(\pi t)}}=1
$$
so you want to compute
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\ln\sqrt{\cos(\pi t)}}{t^2}=
\frac{1}{2}\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\ln\cos(\pi t)}{t^2}
$$
Let's set $\pi t=2u$, so the limit becomes
$$
\frac{\pi^2}{8}\lim_{u\to0^+}\frac{\ln(1-2\sin^2u)}{u^2}
$$
Now recall that $\lim_{z\to0}(\ln(1-z))/z=-1$ and you can write the limit as
$$
-\frac{\pi^2}{8}\lim_{u\to0^+}\frac{2\sin^2u}{u^2}
$$
so the given limit ends up to be $-\pi^2/4$.

Comment: Good manipulation. Didn't strike my mind.

Comment: @Garvil On the other hand, I find that this kind of exercise is just dull. Application of l'Hôpital or Taylor expansion is *much* easier and useful.

Comment: @egreg: $\overbrace{\text{zzz...z}}^{65}$ dull, so far ;-)

Answer (score 10):

Recall that, as $u \to 0$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\cos u& =1-\frac {u^2}{2}+\mathcal{O}(u^3)\\
\sin u& =u+\mathcal{O}(u^3)\\
\ln (1+u)&=u-\frac {u^2}{2}+\mathcal{O}(u^3)
\end{align}
$$ giving, as $x \to \infty$,
$$
\cos\frac{\pi}{x}=1-\frac{\pi^2}{2x^2}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)
$$ 
$$
\begin{align}
\log \left(\cos\frac{\pi}{x}\right)&=\log \left(1-\frac{\pi^2}{2x^2}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\right)\\\\
\log \left(\cos\frac{\pi}{x}\right)&=-\frac{\pi^2}{2x^2}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\\\\
\log \left(\sqrt{\cos\frac{\pi}{x}}\right)&=-\frac{\pi^2}{4x^2}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)
\end{align}
$$ and
$$
\begin{align}
\sin \left(\log \left(\sqrt{\cos\frac{\pi}{x}}\right)\right)&=-\frac{\pi^2}{4x^2}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\\\\
x^2\sin \left(\log \left(\sqrt{\cos\frac{\pi}{x}}\right)\right)&=-\frac{\pi^2}{4}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)
\end{align}
$$ giving $-\dfrac{\pi^2}{4}$ for the desired limit.

Comment: While this is a good answer (and I upvoted it), I would just like to add a disclaimer for the OP: this answer uses Taylor's expansions of functions, a tool which is very often very similar to using L'Hospital's rule (in that it brings in derivatives).

Comment: Thanks. I never thought of series expansion.

Comment: @Garvil You are welcome. Taylor series expansion is a powerful tool to find out these kinds of limits. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Using $\lim\limits_{t\to0}\frac{\sin(t)}t=1$ and $\lim\limits_{t\to0}\frac{\log(1-t)}t=-1$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}x^2\sin\left(\log\left(\sqrt{\cos(\pi/x)}\right)\right)
&=\pi^2\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin\left(\frac12\log(\cos(t))\right)}{t^2}\\
&=\pi^2\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\frac12\log(\cos(t))}{t^2}\frac{\sin\left(\frac12\log(\cos(t))\right)}{\frac12\log(\cos(t))}\\
&=\pi^2\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\frac14\log(\cos^2(t))}{t^2}\cdot1\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}4\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\log\left(1-\sin^2(t)\right)}{t^2}\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}4\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin^2(t)}{t^2}\frac{\log\left(1-\sin^2(t)\right)}{\sin^2(t)}\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}4\left(\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}\right)^2\cdot(-1)\\[4pt]
&=-\frac{\pi^2}4
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Simplest possible answer +1

Comment: How did $(\pi)^2$ come out?

Comment: @Garvil: We are using the substitution $x=\pi/t$.

Comment: Oh, OK. Thanks.